# Eclipse checkout SVN for JUnit testing

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, svn, maven, junit

Im using Eclipse Juno. I imported a SVN (Subversion) project. I am trying to unit test the java classes on a module. I am using Java Perspective.

build path library has Junit4.

I have this Problems:

1. When im adding a new JUnit test case, the textbox from "class under test" has an error of "class under test doesnt exist in current project". But I just right clicked the java class I want to be tested and add new JUnit Test Case.So basically the error showing up doesnt make any sense. Because the class under test exist.
2. Theres no "run as JUnit Test" in the existing Java Test Class imported from SVN.
   if I right clicked the test class > run as > run config only    ***Theres no Junit Test

Eclipse Setup is Default except this settings:

in Window> Preferences > Java> Installed JRE > Jdk 1.7
in Window> Preferences > Maven > Installtion > Maven 3.0.4 (External)

Please Help me, consider me as a newbie in Unit Testing and in SVN Projects. I dont have any idea what to do.

Can anyone teach me how to create a Junit Test Case from a test class of a SVN Project.
Can You also Instruct the proper Eclipse Settings. (Files and Instructions)

Thanks in advance.

[image: error image]
[image: error image 2]

Comment: Can you run the JUnit tests with `mvn test` outside of Eclipse?

Comment: I dont know how to do that sir, can you teach me how? thanks

Comment: Open a terminal,  `cd` into your project's directory and type `mvn test`. If you have a correct JUnit test somewhere under src/test/java, it should be executed by that command.

Answer (score 0):

Add JUnit to your buildpath and it will solve some or both of your problems. I just tested this on Indigo though I couldn't recreate your first issue.

Comment: Has Eclipse recognised the project as a Java project? Could you post a screenshot of your workspace? I would suggest creating a simple project to test your use of JUnit and work from there.

Comment: Your screenshot is cropped in such a way that the relevant information isn't shown. Project structure is missing for example.